# How can I change text in HTML tag span?

Tags: javascript, html

```
//I am trying change text after click on it in web page

text = document.querySelector(".text");
text.addEventListener("click", changeText=()=> {
 
    text = document.textContent = "NewText";

});
```

But it is not working. Why? I have try to use innerHTML? but it isnot working yet...

Comment: You are trying to set `document.textContent` instead of `text.textContent`

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `text.textContent` instead of `document.textContent` to the new value.

```js
text = document.querySelector(".text");
text.addEventListener("click", function() {
     text.textContent = "NewText";
});
```

```html
<span class="text">Text</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning `text` to `document.textContent`, which is not what you want.

```js
// Get a reference to the element you'll want to change
text = document.querySelector(".text");

// Set up an event handler on that element
text.addEventListener("click", changeText=()=> {
    // Change the .textContent of that element:
    text.textContent = "NewText";

    // Within the DOM element event handler, you can also 
    // refer to the element that the event was triggered on
    // with the "this" keyword, so you could also do this:
    //this.textContent = "NewText";
});
```

```html
<span class="text">Original Text</span>
```